# Cant install steam on Debian 11 (Parrot OS 5.1 (Electro Ara) x86_6)

Tags: steam

When i try to install steam i get these unmet dependencies.

└──╼ $sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.2.131.2) but it is not going to be installed
steam:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

tried to install the dependencies manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed the issue

first i installed aptitude

- sudo apt install aptitude

then

- sudo aptitude install steam

i answered no to this

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1. ```
   steam:i386 [Not Installed]
   ```

   Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
2. ```
   steam-devices recommends steam
   ```

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

then i answered yes to this

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
  Install the following packages:
```

(had to install 39 packages)

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y

then i answered yes to continue

Need to get 46.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 179 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y

after that it worked fine.

apologies for bad format. this is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

Just Download it from flakpak.com

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).